# What are the way to checkout a single file from svn for mac

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I am facing a lot of problems to checkout a single file in svn. am using latest version svn but it is not working on mac  so can please suggest how it will work on mac am waiting for your need full replay.

Comment: Define `it is not working on mac`. What exactly have you tried so far? What outcome did you hope for? What did you get instead? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Subversion does not support checking out single files. The smallest unit you can check out is a directory.

Subversion on the Mac works the same as it does on all other platforms.